# Agregar espacio entre párrafos

Tags: python, python-3.x, docx

Buenas tardes vengo realizando un documento en Word usando la biblioteca [docx](https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) pero cuando intento hacer un salto de línea siempre sigue pegado al párrafo anterior:

```
hash = doc.add_paragraph()
run = hash.add_run(text_hash)
run.font.name = "Arial"
hash.alignment = WD_PARAGRAPH_ALIGNMENT.JUSTIFY
run.add_break()
```

incluso intenté agregar un salto de línea dentro del texto pero no se separa. Espero puedan ayudarme gracias

Comment: Un salto de linea no termina el parrafo, sólo provoca empezar una línea nueva dentro del mismo párrafo. Prueba a crear un párrafo nuevo.

Comment: @abulafia gracias... ya lo intenté pero por alguna razón tampoco lo separa     'k = doc.add_paragraph()
rk = k.add_run()
rk.add_break()'

Comment: Intenta aumentar el espaciado entre párrafos, por ejemplo: `from docx.shared import Pt;
doc.styles['Normal'].paragraph_format.space_after = Pt(50)`

Comment: Ya lo pude hacer... la mejor manera fue al final del párrafo agregar un salto y agregar un espacio en blanco así (w = "hola mundo \n " )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo pude solucionar agregando un salto de linea al final del texto y adicionando uno salto de línea fuera del texto, por alguna razón solo funciona con los dos juntos. Gracias por su apoyo

```
w = "hola mundo \n"+"\n"
```